# What is the typical DRAM row buffer size? How to find it?

Tags: cpu-architecture, ram

How can I find DRAM row buffer size programmatically or by using already existing tools in say a *nix system ?

Comment: due to some strange issue, I cant add computer-architecture tag. it automatically gets changed to cpu-architecture

Comment: Yeah, it's a tag-synonym so any attempt to use the other one turns into cpu-architecture, for good or ill.  People who follow that tag know that it also includes computer architecture, not *just* CPU microarchitecture.  This is clearly not computers-*science*, though, just pure engineering.  Please don't add wrong tags.

Comment: On an x86 PC running GNU/Linux, `sudo dmidecode` can show you that model name/number of your DIMMs, but not their DRAM page size / aka row size.  (I think row buffers are always as wide as a whole row).  I'd guess you'd need something more specific to DRAM to read the config data from the DRAM or memory controller.

Comment: Some computers can access the SPD chip on the DIMMs via a specific eeprom reader connected to the SMBus. If that's the case you can use `i2cdetect -l` to find out the i2c bus number N of the SMBus controller and then `i2cdetect N` to probe the devices on the bus (SPD readers are in the address range 0x50-0x57). If found, `decode-dimms` will decode the DIMMs info. Note however that laptops don't typically have a SPD reader (besides the one in the Mem controller and not exposed to the SW) because laptops are seldom disassembled (compared to desktop PCs).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an example, with a Kingston DDR4, I executed the following commands (you might need to install some packages) :

```
  sudo modprobe eeprom
  decode-dimms
```

These commands, among many information, give me the characteristics of my DDR stick:

```
---=== Memory Characteristics ===---
Maximum module speed                             2132 MHz (PC4-17000)
Size                                             16384 MB
Banks x Rows x Columns x Bits                    16 x 16 x 10 x 64
SDRAM Device Width                               8 bits
Ranks                                            2
Rank Mix                                         Symmetrical
AA-RCD-RP-RAS (cycles)                           14-14-14-35
Supported CAS Latencies                          16T, 15T, 14T, 13T, 12T, 11T, 9T
```

Rows and columns are actually number of address bits (you can check the decode-dimms source at https://fossies.org/linux/i2c-tools/eeprom/decode-dimms, and understand what the code is doing when you look at the DDR4 SPD information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_presence_detect#DDR4_SDRAM)

Thus, if we have 10 column bits, we have 1024 columns (2^10), where each column is composed of the module width (64 as per the data above, represented as "bits"). Since we can also see that the SDRAM device width is 8x, we can deduce that the DIMM locksteps 8 SDRAM chips (those black boxes you see in your DRAM stick) to get that total width of 64 bits.

The row buffer size in my DDR4 is, therefore, 64 bits * 1024 columns = 65536 bits wide (8192 Bytes). Row buffer sizes in DDR3 and DDR4 are mostly this length, but new architectures such as HMC and HBM have different sizes.

So, in one short commandline, to return in bits (just divide by 8 to get bytes):
`decode-dimms | grep "Columns x Bits" | awk -F 'x' '{print (2^$(NF-1))*$NF}`

PS: mind you, this handles a single DIMM. if you have multiple DIMMS decode-dimms might return information for multiple modules.